# How manipulate query results from cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've trying to create a list with the results from a column. I execute the query and the result are okay, but when I input the data in a list using `list.append` they return just `[]`.

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/psw@localhost')

cur = con.cursor()
list = []

cur.execute('select column from table')
for result in cur.fetchall():
    list.append
    print (list)

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Return:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

When I put the results in to a list and return an index, like `results[0]` they just print the first letter of the results like:

```
E
X
A
M
P
L
E
```

When I just expecting:

```
Example
```

There's something wrong with my code? Best Regards, community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple different issues with your code.

**1)**

```
list.append
```

Append what? `append` is a method on list objects, and you need to call it with an **argument**. In your case,

```
 list.append(result)
```

would do what you would expect - it appends `result` to the list called `list`.

<sub>**Note**: The reason this doesn't produce an error is that you don't even *call* the `append` function, you just reference it.
 And in Python it's legal for an instruction to be just an expression - the result of that expression then will get silently discarded when running as a script (as opposed to the interactive interpreter, where the results of expressions will be automatically printed for you).</sub>

<sub>So for example having `42 == 7` on a single line in a script is perfectly legal. It won't do anything (the result of that expression, `False`, will be silently discarded), but it also won't cause an error.</sub>

**2)**

```
    print (list)
```

You're doing this inside the loop, meaning this will be executed once **for every iteration** of the loop - 3 times in your example, because apparently `select column from table` gives three results. Number 1) above is why you get an empty list (`[]`), and this is why you get the empty list three times (`[] [] []`).

You'll probably want to move this **outside** the loop by decreasing it's indenation (move it 4 spaces to the left) - then the list's contents will only be printed once, at the end of the loop.

**3)**

> When I put the results in to a list and return an index, like `results[0]` they just print the first letter of the results like [...]

I don't fully understand what exactly you mean by that, but:

In Python, strings, just like lists, are also **sequences** (a string is a sequence of characters). That means that some operations can be done on both, like indexing (the `sequence[index]` syntax) or looping over them (`for item in sequence`).

Now, if you ever get a result like

```
E
X
A
M
P
L
E
```

in Python, that means that you treated an object that really is a *string* in a way that suggests you were assuming it was a *list* (or some other kind of sequence). For example, if

```
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

or

```
for i in range(len(results)):
    print(results[0])
```

leads to this behavior, then `results` is actually a string, and not a list as you expected.

---

So to summarize, you probably want something like this:

```
# ...

results = []

cur.execute('select column from table')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    results.append(row)

# print the entire list
print(results) 

# print the first row by addressing it via index
print(results[0])

# print the first column of the third row
print(results[2][0])

# ...
```

Note though, that cursor results always will be **database rows** - even if you just select one column.

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted the code with some errors but I think you understood clearly. I tried to use lists acessing by row and column and I'm think that way it's more confortable. I'm following your example to continue with my tests here and they work very well. Thank you very much, Lukas! Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, and thanks for your feedback. Have a nice day too :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to run the sql select statement from some tool like DB visualizer what does your results look like? That would simply confirm that there is nothing wrong with your sql statement.

In a project I use cx_Oracle on I have a function used for querying my oracle db which is as shown below. You can pass the sql statment as sql to the function.

```
def execute_query_result_set(sql, args=(), one=False):
    print "execute_query_result_set()"
    con = ""
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(_connection_string)

    try:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        return results
    finally:
        if con != "":
            con.close()
```

This function returns a list of the results of your query. If you are selecting more than just one column it will return as a list of tuples [('value', 'other'), ('another', 'row'), ('some', 'more'), ('etc', 'etc')]

If are not looking to have a separate function to call, you could simply just do

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(your_db_connection_string)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(your_sql_select_statement)
results = cursor.fetchall()
con.close()
```

Then the variable results should be a list of your results, and then you can do whatever you need with that list. Hopefully that will help

Comment: I did some tests and the function return the right list as turples, but isn't what I want, I want put these results in a list to access they indexes.

Comment: So you should be able to still do that but it will just be accessed with then results[x][y] where x and y are integers and x would be a database row, then y would be the column from the row. I use that type of method throughout my project. You should still be fully able to access them

Comment: But, it's just one column, this rule apply?

Comment: @GrazieleGalvão yes, even if you select just one column, this still applies.

Comment: @LukasGraf your answer is much more educational then my own, I would comment on yours but don't have enough rep yet

Comment: @stephen thanks ;) Yours is good advice too though, in terms of best practices and encapsulating access to the DB API. Though at some point I probably would recommend to move to [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to get one more layer of abstraction - it nicely abstracts away some of the nasty details that Oracle and cx_Oracle bring with them.

Comment: @LukasGraf interesting, I will definitely be checking that out next chance I get

Comment: Thank you guys, both of your answers help a lot. I'm following the way replyed by Lukas. Thank you, @stephen for explain about access the row :)